# Does p2p(peer to peer) die? or just not being used? and can servive?

Tags: p2p

I know p2p network, especially blockchain and torrent, has no centralized head. Then how they can be died?
And if the network do not longer being used, can it be survived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P2P is not dying, it is only very rarely used for applications as it is much easier to develop a centralized system. In addition, it is much easier for the developer to maintain a centralized system.
So if such a P2P network is no longer used, it does not have to be "dead". For example, with a P2P chat, it doesn't matter, because you simply can't chat with anyone as long as nobody use it. With a blockchain, however, it would be quite a huge problem, because it would be like a centralization and it would be easier to take control about the blockchain with a 51% attack.